# Cannot setup raspberry pi 3

Tags: raspbian, ssh, raspbian-stretch, setup

I have purchased Raspberry Pi 3.

- Then I downloaded the RASPBIAN STRETCH WITH DESKTOP.
- Then I formatted the SD Card (16 GB) with SD Card Formatter.
- Then I wrote the downloaded RASPBIAN image into the SD Card using WIN32DISKIMAGER.
- Then I Created one blank file in the root Directory named as 'ssh' without extention.

Inserted the card into Raspberry Pi, connected the power supply, connected the LAN cable to my laptop, and shared the connection with WIFI from the Network Settings.

I followed the steps to connect to the PI using Putty. using raspberrypi.mshome.net and clicked the 'Enable X11 forwarding'.

When I click open it says 'Unable to open connection to raspberrypi.mshome.net Host does not exist.'

I used Advanced IP Scanner, nut it does not show Raspberry Pi device.

Can Any one guide me setting up the Raspberry Pi?

Comment: If you put the SD card in your windows system, what do you see in the root folder?

Comment: Your question is unclear - WHAT you did exactly and on WHAT. It appears you are using ICS on your laptop. You can have **EITHER** ICS or `ssh` access to the Pi - **NOT BOTH**. Similar questions have been asked hundreds of times.

Comment: You can follow [this](https://medium.com/@tisutisu/bring-up-raspberry-pi-without-a-monitor-or-keyboard-26dc14d953a0) guide to setup your raspberry pi headless.

Answer (score 1):

The green LED should do one of three things when you plug the Pi in:

1. #### Comes on solid and stays on.

   The SD card is not being read; if you try taking the card out and plugging it in, it will do exactly the same thing (check to confirm; the Pi 2 may instead have the LED off).

   You can try creating the card again, or if you are sick of that, try a different SD card.  If it still does not work and you have [followed the instructions to the letter](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/README.md), the Pi may be defective and you should find out about returning it to the distributor.
2. #### Flashes in a regular rhythm.

   This will be about a 1 or 2 Hz pattern, then a slightly longer pause, and repeat.  The number of [flashes in the pattern indicates the specific problem](https://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Green_LED_blinks_in_a_specific_pattern), but the underlying issue is most likely that the card was corrupted at some point. You should try to recreate as per number one above.
3. #### Flashes rapidly and intermittently for about 30 seconds, then goes off.

   This may be a bit shorter or longer, but if it is between 10 seconds and two minutes very likely the boot has succeeded.

   In this case you are probably going to need a screen, keyboard, and mouse to sort out your problems.

   However:

> connected the LAN cable to my laptop, then shared the connection with WIFI ... using raspberrypi.mshome.net ... Advanced IP Scanner it does not show raspberry pi device

If you are sharing Wifi via Windows, surely there is a definitive way to tell whether the thing on the other end of the Ethernet cable is connected to the laptop?  You don't even need to share wifi for that, and you should be able to tell the OS to assign it a static IP on an arbitrary subnet (i.e., not your LAN) -- *it has to do that anyway if it is forwarding to the wifi network.*

Put another way, **you need to investigate the software you are using on the laptop.  It is impossible for the pi to be connected directly via an ethernet cable yet Windows does not know what is going on.**  Using an IP scanner to solve this "mystery" is like phoning someone who is sitting next to you.  The OS already knows the answer.  You can find out with certainty whether the pi is connected or not without any need for scanning, and if so what IP address it can be reached at.